# How do I make XCode show me warnings in my C code?

Tags: c, xcode

When I build using a Makefile I add `-Wall -g` to my `gcc` args to get warnings.

So when I build this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
}
```

I get this warning:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:10: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

However when I build the same code in XCode I don't see any warnings.

I think XCode is using LLVM instead of GCC but there must be an equivelant. How can I turn this on in XCode?

Comment: We need more information. What version of Xcode and Mac OS X? Anything built with clang should show a similar warning. You'll also need to enable -Wall under "Other compiler options" since it isn't enabled by default.

Comment: For Xcode 3, click on the little warning icon in the lower right of any window and a window of error messages will pop up.  For Xcode 4 you select the correct "navigator view" for build errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think XCode is using LLVM instead of GCC but there must be an equivelant. How can I turn this on in XCode?

You can choose the compiler from the build options area.

1. Click the project in the navigator
2. Click the desired target
3. Click Build Settings
4. set `GCC_VERSION` in the search field below.
5. Choose the compiler to use.

If you clear the search field now, you can scroll down to enable specific warnings.

Note that LLVM + GCC is the GCC front end with a LLVM optimizer.

Clang doesn't support all the options GCC does. It also supports a few new ones, or differences. So it's a good idea to build against both.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is probably the issue. I played around some more and got _other_ warnings to show, just not the specific one I was looking for. So my guess is that LLVM just doesn't have that warning, at least with my current configuration.